# Android SQLite How to output all database fields to a listView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my database handler class
`

```
public class myDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todoDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_TODO = "todo";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TODONAME = "todoName";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";



    public myDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TODO + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_TODONAME + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add a new row to the database
    public void addTODO(TODO todo){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TODONAME, todo.get_todoname());
        values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,todo.get_description());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_TODO, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    //Delete a TO DO from the database
    public void deleteTODO(String TODOName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " WHERE " + COLUMN_TODONAME + "=\"" + TODOName + "\";");
    }

    public void editTODO(String TODOName, String newDescription){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String queryUpdate = "UPDATE" + TABLE_TODO + "SET" + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + "=\"" + newDescription + "WHERE" + COLUMN_TODONAME + "=\"" + TODOName + "\";";
        db.execSQL(queryUpdate);
    }

    public String dbToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " WHERE 1";

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Move to the first row in your results
        c.moveToFirst();

        //Position after the last row means the end of the results
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("todoName")) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("todoName"));
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description"));

                dbString += "\n";
            }


            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();

        return dbString;
    }      
}
```

How can I output the columns todoName & description to a list view in a separate activity, so that a select * statement displays the columns for these. code here:

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong Statement**

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " WHERE 1"; // WHERE 1 =??
```

**Query will not exist**

Enhance your **WHERE** Statement **DEMO**

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " WHERE " + FIELD_ID + " = '" + field_id_value + "'";
```

**Fetching all Value**

```
  // Select All Fields
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO ;
```

Comment: `WHERE 1` is the same as not putting any WHERE clause (it means **always true**). Therefore, it's not wrong at all. But it's very prone to *SQL injection*. Therefore, it's actually not adviceable.

Comment: @Rotwang okay sir